# String key from string identifier

Tags: android

I have string identifier. I want to know string key name, not value.

```
e.g 
<string name="hi">"Hello value" </string>

public void getStringKey(int identifier){
// return hi
}
```

Any idea please

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public String getStringByString(String key) {
    String retString="";
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(key, "string", getPackageName());
    if (id != 0) {
        retString = getString(id);
        Log.e("Identifier",""+id);
        Log.e("Key",""+getResources().getResourceEntryName(id));
        Log.e("Value",""+retString);
    }
    return retString;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do think this is possible using

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int identifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResources().getResourceName(int resid);` to get complete name "**com.example.app:id/hi**"

Use `getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);` to get only name "**hi**"

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve identifier by using this

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(id_of_resource);
```